# jQuery module function is unexpectedly returning 'Uncaught TypeError'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I'm trying to use the module pattern to build a search function:

> https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

```
 $("#search").click(function(){
        var searchFunc = (function(){   
            event.preventDefault();     

            var term = $("#searchInput").val();
            var warning = $('#searchErrors');
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/;
            var keyboard = $(':focus');
            var error = null;

            var validateTerm = function(term){
                if (term === ''){
                    var error = 'Please enter a search term';
                }
                else if (!regex.test(term)){
                    var error = 'Please enter only alphanumeric characters (numbers and letters).';
                }
                return error;
            };

            var displayErrors = function(error){
                warning.append(error).show();
            };

            keyboard.blur();
        })();

        searchFunc.validateTerm(term);
        if (error != null){
            displayErrors.empty();
            searchFunc.displayErrors(error);    
        }
        else{
            return returnResults(term);     
        }
    });

    var returnResults = (function(term) {
        console.log(term);
    })();
```

When running I get this error:

> script.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateTerm'
>   of undefined

I'm clicking the `#search` button with a blank `#searchInput` field, expecting the searchFunc to validate the term and then show the `#searchErrors` div with my error message appended to it. What is causing this error?

Comment: did you tried replacing `var validateTerm = function(term){` with `this.validateTerm = function(term){` ?\

Comment: above `searchFunc.validateTerm(term);` do a console.log of term and it will more than likely be undefined - try adjusting line 5 to read `var term = $("#searchInput").val() || "";` - more than likely you have a typo in the naming of your search term box id

Comment: And which is line 28 in your script?

Comment: Line 28 is:  searchFunc.validateTerm(term);

Comment: I do not think you followed the pattern correctly. Search function is undefined since that is what you define it. And you have a random event.preventDefault() inside the method when it makes no sense to have it there.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the code above that would either A) Make `searchTerm` be anything but `undefined`, or B) Make it have a `validateTerm` property on it if it were. The function you're calling when assigning to `searchTerm` doesn't return anything, and thus calling it results in `undefined`. Declaring a variable inside a function does nothing to make that variable accessible outside the function (fortunately).

I can't make out what you're trying to do with your code, but the module pattern fundamentally looks like this (with ES5 and earlier):

```
var thing = (function() {
    function foo() {
    }

    function bar() {
    }

    return {
        foo: foo
    };
})();
```

Key things:

1. We return something, usually an object
2. We assign properties to that object to reveal things outside the "module" (scoping function).

Other formations:

```
var thing = (function() {
    function bar() {
    }

    return {
        foo: function foo() {
        }
    };
})();
```

Or

```
var thing = (function() {
    var t = {};

    function bar() {
    }

    t.foo = function foo() {
    };

    return t;
})();
```

Or with ES2015 (currently you still need to transpile to use ES2015 in the wild):

```
var thing = (function() {
    function bar() {
    }

    return {
        foo() {
        }
    };
})();
```

All of those result in `thing` referring to an object (the one we create with the object initializer on the `return`) with a property `foo` referring to the `foo` function, and a completely private `bar` function that only `foo` can access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my comment above was (possibly) incorrect.

In your validateTerm function you are defining 'error' within each if block - there is no way to access this outside the if block.

If you define error outside the if statements it will return correctly. (for clarity I have renamed it to returnError so you can see the difference between error defined above and the error within your function.)

```
var validateTerm = function(term){
            var returnError = "";
            if (term === ''){
                returnError = 'Please enter a search term';
            }
            else if (!regex.test(term)){
                returnError = 'Please enter only alphanumeric characters (numbers and letters).';
            }
            return returnError;
        };
```

Additionally I can see that you have defined 'error' previously - so I am guessing you want to ammend the validate line to be as follows:-

```
error = searchFunc.validateTerm(term);
```

As you want to assign the value you have returned from the function to the error variable to use later on.